# Using the pipe in unique() function in r is not working

Tags: r, function, magrittr

I have some troubles using the pipe operator (%>%) with the unique function.

```
df = data.frame(
  a = c(1,2,3,1),
  b = 'a')

unique(df$a) # no problem here
df %>% unique(.$a) # not working here
# I got "Error: argument 'incomparables != FALSE' is not used (yet)"
```

Any idea?

Comment: You can set the incomparables argument to FALSE, for example: `df %>% unique(.$a, incomparables = FALSE)`. Alternatively, I would recommend using `filter` with `!duplicated`, for example: `df %>% filter(!duplicated(a))`

Comment: @GeorgeWood But why does `.$a` override the default value of `incomparables`?

Comment: Thats still a strange behavior. df %>% mean(.$a) works. So what is the problem with unique() ?

Comment: When I run `df %>% mean (.$a)` i get `In mean.default(., .$a) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As other answers mention : `df %>% unique(.$a)` is equivalent to `df %>% unique(.,.$a)`.

To force the dots to be explicit you can do:

```
df %>% {unique(.$a)}
# [1] 1 2 3
```

An alternative option from `magrittr`

```
df %$% unique(a)
# [1] 1 2 3
```

Or possibly stating the obvious:

```
df$a %>% unique()
# [1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 8):

What is happening is that `%>%` takes the object on the left hand side and feeds it into the first argument of the function by default, and then will feed in other arguments as provided. Here is an example:

```
df = data.frame(
  a = c(1,2,3,1),
  b = 'a')

MyFun<-function(x,y=FALSE){
  return(match.call())
}
> df %>% MyFun(.$a)
MyFun(x = ., y = .$a)
```

What is happening is that `%>%` is matching `df` to `x` and `.$a` to `y`.

So for `unique` your code is being interpreted as:

`unique(x=df, incomparables=.$a)`

which explains the error.  For your case you need to pull out `a` before you run unique. If you want to keep with `%>%` you can use `df %>% .$a %>% unique()`  but obviously there are lots of other ways to do that.