# Using unique to obtain a vector of UserId's that satisfy a criterion without creating an intermediate dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, unique

I have a data frame with time series data for multiple subjects, and want to extract a vector of unique UserIds that meet a criterion for the number of days on which the subject answered a set of questions

```
    > df_all_rows
                                 UserId Answer_Date Q1_Daily Q2_Daily Q3_Daily Q4_Daily Q5_Daily
1  1f3edec4-38c9-44f3-9931-942ccba98203 2017-01-26        7        8        8        8        5        
2  202e6c2f-0b78-4ae2-9b60-4116a7241199 2017-03-11        6        4        5        3        6        
3  23124514-338b-46cf-8fa8-f4fea09f3d87 2017-04-05        3        3        4        1        3        
4  23124514-338b-46cf-8fa8-f4fea09f3d87 2017-04-06        3        3        4        1        2        
5  23124514-338b-46cf-8fa8-f4fea09f3d87 2017-04-07        3        3        4        1        2        
6  23124514-338b-46cf-8fa8-f4fea09f3d87 2017-04-08        3        3        2        2        1        
7  23124514-338b-46cf-8fa8-f4fea09f3d87 2017-04-09        3        3        4        1        2        
8  23124514-338b-46cf-8fa8-f4fea09f3d87 2017-04-10        3        3        4        2        2        
9  2354d580-4065-404a-8a3e-154dc83900d3 2017-04-21        9        9        8        8        9        
10 4ab5911d-767f-47db-b937-f1b2f3735ff7 2017-07-27        5        3        2        0        1        
11 59eeda84-53cc-47fd-b2b0-23bfaa6cbde7 2017-04-04        3        2        1        5        2        
12 59eeda84-53cc-47fd-b2b0-23bfaa6cbde7 2017-04-05        3        2        1        5        5
```

I tried the following code snippet:

```
subjects <- df_all_rows %>% 
              group_by(UserId) %>%
              filter(n() >= n_required) %>% 
              unique(UserId)
```

Unfortunately the last step does not work: I get the following error message:

```
Error in isFALSE(incomparables) : object 'UserId' not found
```

It's easy enough to create a new data frame (call it df_tmp) using the first three lines of this segment and then writing

```
subjects <- unique(df_tmp[["UserId"]])
```

but surely there must be a way to do this in one step instead of two without creating another dataframe?

I'd be very appreciative for guidance with my problem.

Sincerely

Thomas Philips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
Error in isFALSE(incomparables) : object 'UserId' not found
```

This error means that unique is actually looking for a variable with the name `UserId`. Of course, this does not exist.

#### unique

In case you want to use `unique`, the following should work according to [this post (Using the pipe in unique() function in r is not working)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49408253/using-the-pipe-in-unique-function-in-r-is-not-working).

```r
subjects <- df_all_rows %>% 
              group_by(UserId) %>%
              filter(n() >= n_required) %>% 
              {unique(.$UserId)}
```

#### with pure tidy

As pointed out below by user MrFlick in the comments below, you can also use the following in case you want a pure tidy version.

```r
subjects <- df_all_rows %>% 
              group_by(UserId) %>%
              filter(n() >= n_required) %>% 
              pull(UserId) %>% unique()
```

or you could try using [distinct](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/distinct.html). See also [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/distinct_all.html).

HTH!

Comment: Works like a charm - thank you! I don't quite understand the need for the curly braces around unique as well as the need for .$ ahead of UserId, but I will read the posts you reference. Thanks again.

Comment: Great! The answer to that question is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49408685/13397655). Please consider marking my answer as correct as well as giving it an UpVote. Thank You!

Comment: A tidy alternative to `{unique(.$UserId)}` would be `pull(UserId) %>% unique()`